# ImportExcel: How to insert an multi-dimensional array of values

Tags: powershell

I'm using ImportExcel module and I'm trying to insert an array of values.

```
$file = "C:\Temp\Test.xlsx"

$data = @(("header1","header2","header3"),(2,5,8),(3,6,9))

$excel = $data | Export-Excel -WorksheetName "Sheet1" -Path $file -PassThru

Close-ExcelPackage $excel -Show
```

But data are inserted in one column instead of the range A1:C3.

[image]

I need to find a way how to insert an array of values.

Comment: You have `header2` defined twice

Comment: @Theo Thanks, but it should not have an affect on the result. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the multi-dimensional array into an array of objects like this

```
$data = ("header1","header2","header3"),(2,5,8),(3,6,9) | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -join ','
} | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

to produce

```
header1 header2 header3
------- ------- -------
2       5       8      
3       6       9
```

but this will only work if you do not have duplicate headers in the first array..